# Avoid pandas change plot colors when using **kwds

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I´m working on some EDA with python using pandas to make the plots. The default forman for the plots looks like this:

[image]

But if I made some more complex filtering, like this:

```
s = (coupon_list[[ 'USABLE_DATE_MON', 'USABLE_DATE_TUE', 'USABLE_DATE_WED',
       'USABLE_DATE_THU', 'USABLE_DATE_FRI', 'USABLE_DATE_SAT',
       'USABLE_DATE_SUN','DISCOUNT_PRICE']].melt("DISCOUNT_PRICE", var_name='days', value_name='data')
                .assign(days = lambda x: pd.Categorical(x['days'], 
                                                        ordered=True, 
                                                        categories=days))
                .query('data == 1')
                .groupby("days")['DISCOUNT_PRICE']
                .mean())

s.plot.bar()
```

The format changes to a carnival

[image]

Now I don´t know how to plot it in the same format than the rest of the images.

I tried with the addition argument cmap:

```
s = (coupon_list[[ 'USABLE_DATE_MON', 'USABLE_DATE_TUE', 'USABLE_DATE_WED',
       'USABLE_DATE_THU', 'USABLE_DATE_FRI', 'USABLE_DATE_SAT',
       'USABLE_DATE_SUN','DISCOUNT_PRICE']].melt("DISCOUNT_PRICE", var_name='days', value_name='data')
                .assign(days = lambda x: pd.Categorical(x['days'], 
                                                        ordered=True, 
                                                        categories=days))
                .query('data == 1')
                .groupby("days")['DISCOUNT_PRICE']
                .mean())

s.plot.bar(cmap='Blues_r')
```

But I'm not findding the same colors there:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing is the difference in plotting a `DataFrame` versus a `Series` when using a `bar` plot. You can use `s.to_frame().plot.bar()` to turn you `Series` into a `DataFrame` before you plot to get a single color:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': np.random.randint(1,10,20)})
```

#### DataFrame

```
df[['col1']].plot(kind='bar')
```

[image]

#### Series:

```
df['col1'].plot(kind='bar')
```

[image]

You can see that in the case of bar plot with a `DataFrame` the color is a single value per `Series` and the `Series` are labeled by the column names. When you do a `bar` plot with a Series, a new color is cycled for each index, and no labels are provided by default.

Comment: Thanks! is this just a pandas thing or is it common across languages?

Comment: @LuisRamonRamirezRodriguez I believe this was a decision made by the `pandas` developers. This behavior is speified in their [bar plot docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html) and it makes sense to treat things like this. But it is somewhat jarring the first time you encounter this.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you could try

```
s.plot.bar(color='#1f77b4')
```

Comment: I just made a sample plot with pandas and called `get_c()` on the first line object. But perhaps gimp's pipette would have done the same result in shorter time - on a desktop, but not on a mobile... :)

Comment: `plt.rcParams.get('axes.prop_cycle')` will give you a list of the default `matplotlib` colors in the order it cycles through.