# Set different colors in the bar chart

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

```
x1 = df[['model', 'failure']].groupby('model').sum() # Total number of failures by model
x2 = df[['model', 'failure']].groupby('model').count() # Total number of each model
ptg_model_fail = np.divide(x1, x2) * 100 
ptg_model_fail.columns = ['ptg']
ptg_model_fail = ptg_model_fail.reset_index().sort_values('ptg')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7, 7))
ax.barh(ptg_model_fail['model'], ptg_model_fail['ptg'], color='cyan',edgecolor='k')
ax.set_xlabel('Percentage')
ax.set_title('Failure percentage by model', size=16)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

How can I use different color and control the width of the bars to define different models? Thanks for your time!

Comment: instead of `ax.barh(ptg_model_fail['model'],...)`, plot the bars separately?

Comment: `color` accepts a list of colors.

Comment: By default Series bar plots different colors, but a DataFrame bar plot is the same color: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53905165/avoid-pandas-change-plot-colors-when-using-kwds/53907485#53907485 (so plot the Series)

Comment: @ALollz but isn't OP using `ax.barh`, not `df.plot.barh`?

Comment: @BigBen True, but their code above goes through gymnastics to reset the index and create the columns, all just to call it in that plot, when you could just `ptg_model_fail.plot(kind='barh')` well before making the DataFrame.

Comment: @ALollz well yes I definitely can get on board with simplifying. "Gymnastics" is an accurate description here.